# Illuminatedcloud import/export custom objects and merge standard objects

Tags: illuminatedcloud

I got a brand new [Illuminated cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/support) license for IntelliJ IDEA.

Now I want to transfer custom objects from a dev. organisation to a sandbox one and also merge standard object custom fields as well.

```
| Development             |      Sandbox    |
|:------------------------|----------------:|
| Account's custom fields | Account (merge) |
| Custom object           | custom object   |
```

I was able to fetch every metadata about those objects from my dev. org. with Illuminated cloud but I don't get how to transfert, merge and push them on the other org.

For the moment, I just created a package `objects` on the new project (intelliJ) linked to the sandbox and copy/paste the *.object files from the first project. After that, I am stucked.

Any idea ? Any experiences about doing this ?

Thank you

Comment: Is the project structure right click, illuminated cloud, deploy all metadata. In the dialog Chang to connection to the destination or may have to create new connection. Once done, select custom and pick what you want to deploy. IC is a great tool with idea. Takes a bit of learning though. Wait till you get the offline debugger a run. Nice feature

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer.

When I click on "deploy all metadata", the objects I copy/paste do not appear in the context list.

Comment: ensure you have the appropriate options checked. You may also need to click the refresh icon.